# Ajuste de tamaño de celdas excel mediante c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, xsl, celdas

Estoy trabajando en Visual con SpreadsheetLight
Quiero ajustar el tamaño de la columna al texto, pero no se cual es la propiedad esta es la que estoy utilizndo pero no queda como necesito:

[image: Es la propiedad que le doy al texto]

[image: Es el resultado, pero yo quiero que se vea PRESENTACION todo seguido]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1):

Debes ajustar el ancho de la columna al ancho del texto que quieres poner dentro.

[Aquí](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/42c363ed-e622-4fb3-a054-a6b3207102b7/cambiar-propiedades-ancho-de-celdas-excel?forum=vbes) te dejo un hilo que tratan el tema.

Espero haberte podido ayudar

Comment: GRacias de verdad, acabo de dar con ello¡¡ seria: sl.AutoFitColumn("A11", "I11");

Answer (score 0):

Para ajustar el tamaño de una columna se debe utilizar.

```
 sl.SetColumnWidth(Número de Columna, Ancho);
```

Para ajustar el tamaño de una fila se debe utilizar.

```
 sl.SetRowHeight(Número de fila, alto);
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta que OP hizo, si lees con detenimiento puedes ver que él dice "*Quiero ajustar el tamaño de la columna al texto*". ;).